# Whats the purpose of BaseTemplateName, BaseTemplateID and BaseConfigurationID?

Tags: web-template

What does BaseTemplateName, BaseTemplateID and BaseConfigurationID exacly do? Whats purpose of them in the webtemplate elements.xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These are web templates available to you on the SharePoint installation and the purpose is for you to choose one. This guy explains it a little more.

[Web Templates – What base template should I use?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2011/09/04/web-templates-what-base-template-should-i-use.aspx)